# How to run locally Cypress test on the same port as they are run at gitlab CI?

Tags: javascript, docker, gitlab, cypress, cicd

My Cypress tests are run locally without any problem since they are run on the localhost:

[image]

However, in Gitlab CI the Docker image is created with another IP address and therefore Cypress tests fail:

[image]

How can I fix it? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If I understand the question correctly you just have to change the URL you are visiting.
In the cypress.json file try changing the baseURL to your desired entry point, in this case

```
    "baseUrl": "http://172.17.0.3/"
```

This way you can just

```
    cy.visit('/relativePathEtc')
```

and will be prefixed with the baseUrl.

Source: https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/visit#Prefixes

Comment: Yes, you understand me correctly. I believe, your solution should work. Though after the change in the CI pipeline I get an error 'Cypress could not verify that this server is running: http://172.17.0.3/'

Comment: I believe, that's because in the tests cy.visit('http://localhost:3000') is left. Though I need it to run CY tests locally

Comment: @rumon if you need both URLs I would specify one of them as my base URL (maybe the most used one?) or hardcode them in the tests and forget about the baseUrl. With respect to the other part of the question about Cypress verifying the server is running, it has many potential causes, I suggest searching for the error code. Good luck!